# Passing JSON data from php to html-data attribute and then to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i'm creating a plugin in which the user adds custom settings in `data-` attribute in HTML. Settings are in JSON format. I'm using these settings in Javascript.

It has got `preview`, `base` and `paths` properties. `preview` and `base` have string values, but `paths` is an array of `path` objects.

It works fine when i add JSON setting directly into the HTML:

```
<div data-side="front" data-params='{"preview": "assets/img/products/tshirt/front-preview.png", "base": "assets/img/products/tshirt/front-base.png", "paths": "[{\"name\": \"base\", \"path\": \"M 324.00,33.00 C 324.00,33.00\", \"x\": 92, \"y\": 16, \"height\": 370}, {\"name\": \"collar\", \"path\": \"M 358.00,46.10 C 358.00,46.10\", \"x\": 170, \"y\": 17, \"height\": 21}, {\"name\": \"leftSleeve\", \"path\": \"M 633.17,170.00 C 633.17,170.00\", \"x\": 288, \"y\": 66, \"height\": 131}, {\"name\": \"leftCuff\", \"path\": \"M 595.00,438.00 C 615.47,438.23\", \"x\": 293, \"y\": 172, \"height\": 33}, {\"name\": \"rightSleeve\", \"path\": \"M 142.00,140.00 C 143.46,150.28\", \"x\": 47, \"y\": 64, \"height\": 131}, {\"name\": \"rightCuff\", \"path\": \"M 48.00,375.38 C 48.00,375.38 95.00\", \"x\": 41, \"y\": 166, \"height\": 36}]"}'>
```

I'm getting this value using `data('Params')` method of jQuery. Its type is `object`.

Now, when i'm trying to `json_encode` a php array and pass it to the `data-`, it's added successfully

```
<div data-side="front" data-params=<?php echo "'".json_encode($dataParams)."'"; ?>>
```

But now typeof `data('Params')` in Javascript is `string`. So, i'm getting a JSON parse error. If i remove `paths` key, its type changes to object.

Here's the `print_r` of the array that i'm encoding:

```
Array
(
    [preview] => assets/img/products/tshirt/front-preview.png
    [base] => assets/img/products/tshirt/front-base.png
    [paths] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => base
                    [path] => M 324.00,33.00 C 324.00,33.00
                    [x] => 92
                    [y] => 16
                    [height] => 370
                )
                ... and more path arrays

        )

)
```

So, why does it changes its type to string if i include `paths` key? Any way to solve it?

Edit:

Here's the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Have you checked the output of `json_encode`? Is it the same as you inserted directly?

Comment: Edited my question. Added output

Comment: Do you have any function that puts the json encoded result into html entities? I thought that by default json encode doesnt put quotes into their html entity equivalent

Comment: @Rene Korss 

Wrapping php code around double quotes breaks the json, because i guess json also has double quotes.

Comment: Oh. Correct. Try with single quotes?

Comment: @JammyDodger231

if i'm inspecting the element(using developer tools), it shows quotes, but if i'm i'm copying it (to share here), it encodes quotes as well.

Comment: Ah, my bad didnt realize it was from SO not from your code

Comment: @JammyDodger231

Added screenshot

Comment: @ Rene Korss 

It doesn't shows the output then. Everything wrapped in single quotes is never evaluated.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to escape data and handle special characters.

```
<div data-side="front" data-params="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($dataParams), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```

And get it with jQuery:

```
$('[data-side="front"]').data('params'); // object
```

or javascript

```
JSON.parse(document.querySelector('[data-side="front"]').dataset.params); // object
```

Comment: It Doesn't works. Breaks after the space. HTML output is `<div 324.00,33.00&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:&quot;92&quot;,&quot;y&quot;:&quot;16&quot;,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;370&quot;}]}="" c="" 324.00,33.00="" data-params="{&quot;preview&quot;:&quot;assets\/img\/products\/tshirt\/front-preview.png&quot;,&quot;base&quot;:&quot;assets\/img\/products\/tshirt\/front-base.png&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;:[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;base&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;M" data-side="front">`

Comment: Are you `echo`-ing this div or is it outside of PHP tags? I tested it and it works create for me. And your last image is correct. It should be like this.

Comment: Here's how i'm using it `<div data-side="front" data-params=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($dataParams)); ?>>` . Output is correct, but its type is `string` (in javascript). If i'm adding JSON setting values statically, its type is `object`

Comment: Please copy-paste my code exactly. It has quotes and function parameters. How are you getting it in JS? See my edited post how I get it in jQuery.

Comment: In latest jQuery versions you can use $('[data-side="front"]').attr('data-params');

Comment: or better don't use jQuery at all if everything can be done with the WebAPI: `document.querySelector('[data-side="front"]').dataset.params`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use only ***json_encode()*** with ***JSON_HEX_APOS*** flag which converts all ' symbols to \u0027:

```
<div data-side="front" data-params="<?php echo json_encode($dataParams, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>">
```

Then access them with JavaScript:

```
$('[data-side="front"]').data('params');
```

Comment: Note that it converts just the `'` symbol, not all symbols - it's in the A, but easy to overlook