# JavaScript breaks when there is a double quote in returned JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I've got some simple code which pulls some values from my database, and then attaches this data as a JSON string in a data-attribute on a button to be used when this button is pressed. The problem is, if there is a double quote inside the one of the values returned from the database, I'm guessing that it breaks the JSON.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<td
    uk-toggle="target: #entry_modal"
    class="alter_accessory"
    data-accessory='{{ json_encode(@acc) }}'
>edit</td>
```

Contents of `@acc`

```
Array
(
    [uid] => 23
    [title] => Lenovo 4XB0F86403 ThinkPad 512GB 2.5" Solid-State Drive
    [model] => 4XB0F86403
    [upc] => 888772069421
    [image] => https://www.disctech.com/SCASite/product_images/4XB0F86403_1000-1.jpg
    [category] => lenovo_accessory
)
```

Notice in the title there is a double quote `"`

Here is the javascript which is triggered when this button is clicked:

```
$(".alter_accessory").on('click', function() {

    var data = $(this).data('accessory');
    console.log(data);

    $('#entry_modal_title').text('Edit Accessory');

    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        $('#entry_' + index).val(value);
    });
});
```

Which simply loops through the JSON and changes the value of an input box for each key

However, when I click the button, none of the inputs are filled out and I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in
>   {"uid":"23","title":"Lenovo 4XB0F86403 ThinkPad 512GB 2.5" Solid-State
>   Drive","model":"4XB0F86403","upc":"888772069421","image":"https://www.disctech.com/SCASite/product_images/4XB0F86403_1000-1.jpg","category":"lenovo_accessory"}

How can I resolve this issue?

Requested rendered HTML of a button:

```
<td
    uk-toggle="target: #entry_modal"
    style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"
    class="alter_accessory"
    data-accessory='{"uid":"23","title":"Lenovo 4XB0F86403 ThinkPad 512GB 2.5&quot; Solid-State Drive","model":"4XB0F86403","upc":"888772069421","image":"https:\/\/www.disctech.com\/SCASite\/product_images\/4XB0F86403_1000-1.jpg","category":"lenovo_accessory"}'
>edit</td>
```

(From "View Source")

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187893/discussion-on-question-by-grumpycrouton-javascript-breaks-when-there-is-a-double).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820601/passing-json-data-from-php-to-html-data-attribute-and-then-to-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820601/passing-json-data-from-php-to-html-data-attribute-and-then-to-javascript)...

Comment: You have wrong order of operations there `{{ json_encode(@acc) }}`. You should first call `json_encode` and then insert it into the template otherwise the quotes will not be escaped for use in JavaScript.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Can you explain what was the solution?

Comment: I had to delete the dupe target because it was a mess of misleading answers. Feel free to add an answer explaining what the solution for you was.

Comment: I don't know which templating enginge you are using, but I assume it will replace `@acc` with something resulting in this: `<?= json_encode(htmlspecialchars($acc)) ?>` which is the wrong sequence

Comment: You can vote to close your question as a duplicate of the target proposed by War10ck. There was a different duplicate target before.